# Run time not able to fire the button click event for dynamic buttons

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have generated button run time(in app). but I am not able to handle the fire the event of the button run time. my scenario I have the Two Text box 1 for "Name" and another for "Phone No." and 1 Button "Add". when click on Add button, I dynamically generated the One Text box with two button "Call" and "Remove".

[image]
but when click on 1st or 2nd call button its make a call on always lastly added number.

Code is below :

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        EditText textIn, txtPhoneNo;
        Button buttonAdd;
        LinearLayout container;
        EditText textOut;
        System.Collections.ArrayList arrList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            textIn = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textin);
            txtPhoneNo = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPhoneNo);
            buttonAdd = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.add);
            container = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.container);
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
            View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, null);
            textOut = (EditText)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textout);
            arrList.Add(txtPhoneNo.Text);
            if (textIn.Text != "" && txtPhoneNo.Text != "")
            {
                textOut.SetText(textIn.Text + " : " + txtPhoneNo.Text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                container.AddView(addView);
                Button btnCall = (Button)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnCall);
                btnCall.Click += BtnCall_Click;
                Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.remove);
                buttonRemove.Click += ButtonRemove_Click;
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Field can not be blank.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }

        private void BtnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           string strNo = After(textOut.Text,":");
            callDialog.SetMessage("Call " + strNo + "?");
            callDialog.SetNeutralButton("Call", delegate
            {
                 var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
                callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + strNo));
                StartActivity(callIntent);
            });
            callDialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate { });

            // Show the alert dialog to the user and wait for response.
            callDialog.Show();
        }
}
}

Main.axml


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="name" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="345.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:hint="Phone No." />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Add" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
row.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/remove"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Remove"/>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnCall"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/remove"
      android:text="Call"/>
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/textout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/remove"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that how I can make call to particular no. but in this case I am able to call only lastly added number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `textOut` everytime `buttonAdd_Click` is invoked. So when a new layout is added `textOut` will always be the last added `EditText`. This is basically a logical error. As per your logic you should having a `List` of `EditText`s rather than a single instance.

```
List<EditText> textOuts; // instead of EditText textOut;
int layoutCount=0;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        textIn = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textin);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPhoneNo);
        buttonAdd = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.add);
        container = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.container);
        textOuts= new List<EditText>();
    }
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i=layoutCount++;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
        View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, null);
        textOuts.Add((EditText)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textout));
        arrList.Add(txtPhoneNo.Text);
        if (textIn.Text != "" && txtPhoneNo.Text != "")
        {
            textOut.SetText(textIn.Text + " : " + txtPhoneNo.Text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            container.AddView(addView);
            Button btnCall = (Button)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnCall);
            btnCall.Click +=delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       string strNo = After(textOuts[i].Text,":");
        callDialog.SetMessage("Call " + strNo + "?");
        callDialog.SetNeutralButton("Call", delegate
        {
             var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
            callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + strNo));
            StartActivity(callIntent);
        });
        callDialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate { });

        // Show the alert dialog to the user and wait for response.
        callDialog.Show();
        };
            Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.remove);
            buttonRemove.Click += ButtonRemove_Click;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Field can not be blank.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

Changing the code like above might fix it. I haven't tested the code myself.

Comment: I am getting and null reference exception at this line textOuts[i] = (EditText)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textout);

Comment: Have you added this line in OnCreate ? textOuts= new List<EditText>(); If null reference exception is thrown even after that, please post the full Exception Stack trace

Comment: thanks for your reply Sorry I forget to add is. really thanks for your help :)

Comment: getting this error "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." at same line

Comment: Issue was that we were trying to set EdiText like this, textOuts[i] = ... Since that is a List, we should have used Add method. Check my Edit, textOuts.Add((EditText)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textout));

Comment: can I stored these Name and Number to xml file whenever next time app is launched then on saved number is populated in container.

Comment: You will need to store in Shared Preference.  That is the persistence storage for Android.  Check Settings Xamarin Component

Comment: thanks for reply do you have any such code to store these dynamically created Name and number in xml file